# Swing: why does JFormattedTextField adds "," on focus lost

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

the question is in the title.

I'm displaying an int number in my textfield but it keeps adding a "," when I exit the field... any ideas why?

for the code lovers :

the onfocuslost calls:

```
if(textStiffness != null){
            String s1 = textStiffness.getText();
            if(s1 != null){
                stiffness = Float.valueOf(s1.replaceAll(",", "")).intValue();
                stiffness = Math.max(0, stiffness);
            }
        }
```

then :

```
if(textStiffness != null){
            textStiffness.setText((""+(int)stiffness).replaceAll(",", ""));

        }
```

I checked the text set in the field and its correct 10000, but then it gets changed to 10,000 and I can't see why

Comment: you have a code snippet?

Comment: could you post the code where for the focus lost action / method ?

Comment: Nah, who needs code. We should be good enough to guess what his code is doing, since we have super powers!

Comment: without code, I would think of (a) a problem on the lost focus action or (b) some bug I never heard about or even (c) perhaps a bad formatting that hides some of the textfield contents

Comment: +1 :) I liked the "code lovers". Good one, it's good to keep a good mood...

Comment: @woliveirajr yes I know... what I want is to not display the ,   I honestly don't know were you got the idea I thought 10,000 was not equal to 10000...

Comment: @Jason : so, sorry, didn't intend to offend you.

Comment: @Jason: you're still not showing us the formatter that the JFormattedTextField is using. That's kind of important.

Comment: "for the code lovers :", it still doesn't help us. I'm sure you've been asked to post a SSCCE before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html), I found some observations:

> Note: Some formatters might update the value constantly, rendering the loss of focus meaningless, as the value is always the same as what the text specifies.
>
> Note that although the JFormattedTextField class inherits the setText method from the JTextField class, you do not usually call the setText method on a formatted text field. If you do, the field's display changes accordingly but the value is not updated (unless the field's formatter updates it constantly).

and also the `setFocusLostBehavior(int)` :

> Specifies the outcome of a field losing the focus. Possible values are defined in JFormattedTextField as COMMIT_OR_REVERT (the default), COMMIT (commit if valid, otherwise leave everything the same), PERSIST (do nothing), and REVERT (change the text to reflect the value).

Answer (score 3):

You're still not showing us the `NumberFormat` that the `JFormattedTextField` is using, and this actually is the **critical** information necessary for solving your problem. I can only assume that you're using a `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()` for the formatter, and if so, if you check the API for this class, you'll see that for this object, the groupingUsed property is set to true by default. You want to set it to false to get rid of your commas.

For e.g. here is my [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that shows your problem and its solution:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FormattedFieldFun {
   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      NumberFormat numberFormatGuFalse = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
      numberFormatGuFalse.setGroupingUsed(false);  // ***** HERE *****
      JFormattedTextField jftFieldGuFalse = 
          new JFormattedTextField(numberFormatGuFalse);

      NumberFormat numberFormatGuTrue = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
      // numberFormatGuFalse.setGroupingUsed(true); // not necessary as is default
      JFormattedTextField jftFieldGuTrue = 
          new JFormattedTextField(numberFormatGuTrue);

      JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      panel.add(jftFieldGuFalse, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      panel.add(jftFieldGuTrue, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("FormattedFieldFun");
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: that's about number instance and if isn't changed Locale ... +1